# laravel how to send request o a controlle with parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on laravel 5

this is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class RequestController extends Controller
{

    public function sendRequest($endPoint, $body)
    {

        return view('response', "d");
    }
}

?>
```

and in my route i handle it like this:

```
Route::post("/request/send", 'RequestController@sendRequest');
```

then in my html i do

```
<form method="post" action="/request/send">
        <textarea id="code" contentEditable="true" name="body"></textarea>
        <input type="text" value="d" name="endPoint" />
        <input type="button" id="formattCode" value="format"/>
        <input type="submit" value="send"/>
    </form>
```

as you see, i do have the body and the endPoint in my html

however i am getting this error

```
ErrorException in RequestController.php line 11:
Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\RequestController::sendRequest()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing values passed as parameters for a POST request is done via the `Request` instance:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RequestController extends Controller
{

    public function sendRequest(Request $request)
    {
        $endPoint = $request->input('endPoint');
        $body = $request->input('body');

        // Do your stuff
    }
}
```

You cand read more about it in the [Laravel HTTP Requests Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#accessing-the-request).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function sendRequest(App\Http\Requests\Request $request)
{
  //$request->all() returns array of all data
  return view('response');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that is possible. I know that you can bind a parameter to a get request, like "/route/route/{id}" and expect variable $id in your controller, but for post, i am not sure. You can try it though.